# Wakanda port forwarding/routing 409 conflict

Tags: server, port, wakanda

I've got a very large JS app built in Wakanda that I'm working on, and suddenly hit a strange issue.

Our Solution has four main projects in it:

- Consumers
- Merchants
- Funders
- Promoters

These projects all have their own functions, and up until recently have had them operating on the same server via different port addresses - 8100, 8101, 8102, 8103. This has worked without a problem, with the localhost as the host in the Settings.waSettings file, and the respective ports set there.

Now, moving to production, we need to have these routing through to the site from subdomains. Because of the way A-records are and not being able to define a port address, we have our .consumer, .merchant etc subdomains all going to the same elastic IP address, and using the Settings.waSettings files in Wakanda to handle the routing of traffic to each project.

We have set all the incoming ports as 80, with it listening for the subdomain name to handle which project to route the user to. This worked yesterday without a hitch for around an hour on the server, before it suddenly stacked itself. For a time, the Wakanda server just stopped each time you attempted to access one of the subdomains. After a while longer it's not crashing each time, but just simply resolving to a '409 Conflict' screen.

My question is, can Wakanda reliably use it's project Settings file to handle requests like this? Or is there a better way to handle this? I know there used to be a thread in the forums on this discussion.

Thanks, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Hello @Aaron, it'll be a good idea to open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues) and attach your settings file to the issue.

Comment: @hamzahik thanks, will do. We're also in discussion with some of the Wak crew in regards to the issue.

Comment: If anyone is experiencing similar issues, there is a thread here: https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/76